# Is it possible to determine if the current thread is the "debugger"?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

In visual studio when debugging code, if you hover over a property, the body of that property will be executed. When that code is executing is it possible to determine that it is being executed due to the debugger and not due to normal code execution?

To be clear, I'm not looking for Debugger.IsAttached. I'm looking for something that I would name "Debugger.IsPaused". Does anything like that exist?

I was hoping that looking at the CurrentThread would reveal something, like being named "Debugger Thread" or having a ManagedThreadID that was meaningful, but the thread is unnamed and the managed thread id is not special.

Comment: I don't know much about C#, but can't you do something like if(thread == Debugger.CurrentThread)?

Comment: Side note: I believe execution of "get property" will be done on original thread, not a "special debugger thread". As hack you probably can try check "is my call stack look suspicious" in property's code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I like the idea of checking for a suspicious stack frame, but sadly the stack looks exactly the same in the debugger as it would normally.

Comment: @Abe I assume you are talking about the EnvDTE Debugger type and not System.Diagnostics.Debugger? I would hope to achieve this without having to take a dependency on the Visual Studio API, but I might look into that for the sake of curiosity.

Comment: Hmmm - VS knows it (shows "evaluation of:..." in stack trace when using immediate window to evaluate propery) but `StackTrace` in the code does not. :(

Comment: If you want to not execute the body of that property when in the debugger, you could just hide the property from the debugger using an attribute like DebuggerHidden.

Comment: @Andy I actually want to execute the property, but I need to disable some locking when executed from the debugger or the property access can will timeout and VS won't show the value.

Comment: Just an idea: Could you go off of something like AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName to see if you are being executed by the IDE?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Good idea, doesn't work though, it's the same app domain. The debugger is one of those things that is "magic" to me still. I hate magic.

Comment: I suspect adding some unrelated code to locking will cause more harm than good. Consider instead have separate no-locking property/fields. Or for one-off investigation simply check global static bool property and set it by hand in debugger... Disabling automatic property evaluation may be good idea too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot find out if your process is being stopped in the debugger basically because your code is not being executed.

As for special cases of expression value evaluation in debugger (Visual Studio) - the following happens: the active-in-debugger thread of your process is being hijacked by the debugger and then some code generated by Visual Studio expression evaluator gets executed *by your thread*. After the evaluation is complete, your thread is stopped again and its state is left unchanged as it was before evaluation. This process is called "funceval". Theoretically, you could somehow analyse call stack trace in your function to find out if it is being called through funceval, but I suspect this is hardly possible due to unmanaged nature of the CLR debugger.

You can read more about funceval more in the corresponding category of Mike Stall's comprehensive CLR debugging blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/category/11475.aspx

Comment: Here is an MSDN thread where Mike Stall answered a very similar question: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8d9ad358-958d-45bf-b48e-4b356c606302/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-being-called-from-funceval